# SSL on multiple subdomains with the same IP

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

I installed a wildard SSL certificate on our server on which we will run multiple subdomains. So I created sub1.domain.com, sub2.domain.com, etc.

I created several vhost files ( etc) and set NameVirtualHost *:443. So far all subdomains are running on a SSL connection. No problems arised. Every subdomains sees his own content and all browsers work perfect.

Is this a correct way to set-up SSL on multiple subdomains? I know you should set an IP per domain with SSL, but what about subdomains? This seems to run without trouble.

That was my first question. My second question is the fact I received an error after libssl has been updated on my ubuntu server. Apache didn't start anymore and gave me the error:

> [error] Server should be SSL-aware but has no certificate configured [Hint: SSLCertificateFile] ((null):0)

It sound something is wrong, but everything worked perfect the last month. As a fix I found  that you can add "http" after the listen in ports.conf, like this:

> Listen 443 http

It doesn't look like a real solution to me. Anyone else knows what exactly is wrong?

So, 
question 1: Is my SSL setup a correct/legal setup?
question 2: What's this error above all about?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an IP per domain with SSL. You only need an IP per certificate that you want to use on the same port. Since you're only using one certificate on the port, you only need one IP. You've done it exactly right.

Comment: Thanks. Glad to hear. Now I only wonder why I got that weird error